# Maven - how to include a 'generic' plugin intended for integration tests?

Tags: java, maven, junit, integration-testing, maven-plugin

I would like to write a plugin which could be used for integration tests. For the simplicity, let's assume it's a simple MOJO:

```
@Mojo(name = "test", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.INTEGRATION_TEST)
public class IntegrationTestPlugin extends AbstractMojo {
    public void execute() {
        ...
    }
}
```

This plugin can be called from another project:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.artifact.id</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

This would make my life easier, as I just have execute the plugin without writing any additional code. To give an idea, the plugin could for example check if `GET http://localhost:8080/<some endpoint>` returns 200 after spawning a local web container, database, ... as required by the project.

I need classes with a name which follows the conventions (`**/IT*.java, **/*IT.java or **/*ITCase.java`), but how are these classes discovered and executed in this case? And how does this relate to the `execute()` of the Mojo?

Simply putting `SomeTestIT.java` in `src/main/test/...` of the project of the plugin (and not in the project which executes the plugin, as you would do without a plugin) isn't going to work. I'm stuck on how to proceed.

How would this work and what should the `execute()` in the Mojo class look like?

Comment: Taken a look at the maven-failsafe-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Not yet, but will do for sure. I did not think that such plugin is relevant for my question, because in this plugin, the test cases (`**/*IT.java` and so on) are outside the plugin. I want to have them inside the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you subclass `AbstractMojo`, among other things, you have to override `getDefaultIncludes()`.
return the ant path style values that you want to include :

```
 @Override
 protected String[] getDefaultIncludes() {
     return new String[]{ "**/IT*.java", "**/*IT.java", "**/*ITCase.java"};
 }
```

You should draw your inspiration from the `maven-failsafe-plugin` source code available on [github](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/master/maven-failsafe-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/failsafe/IntegrationTestMojo.java) used for integration tests execution in Maven.

Comment: It's make sense, thanks, this probably helps me a lot! The only thing I am currently confused is how these `IT*.java` classes will be able to find the parameters as passed to the plugin mojo (set with `@Parameter` annotiation). I probably should add them to some static singleton in the `execute()` of the Mojo, so the `IT*.java` class can access them later on?

Comment: You are welcome. These are not the tests classes that will find the parameters but you mojo that will use its parameters. I think that you should as first step understand the philosophy of mojos

Comment: In my case, I want to have the test cases **in** the plugin. The exact behavior of these test cases depend on the parameters. These parameters are provided to the mojo (as per `@Parameter` on fields). Somehow, I need to be able to pass these parameters to the test cases. I will investigate.